# How can I use Grails DB Migration with Spring Security and the default DB, H2?

Tags: grails, spring-security, h2

I'm running into an exception generated by the **Grails Database Migration** plugin.

In [JIRA](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPDATABASEMIGRATION-16), it says this is a bug won't fixed.

But, I want to use **Spring Security** with the default DB, **H2**, because it's easy to use to make a simple application.

How can I avoid this bug except changing DB to **MYSQL** or **ORACLE**?

---

---

**UPDATE**

Following the solution in JIRA, I changed the name of the column which has made the error, `password`, to `passwd` in User.groovy.

A part of User.groovy shown below.

```
    String username
    String password
    static transients = ['springSecurityService']
    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, unique: true
        password blank: false
    }
    static mapping = {
        password column: '`passwd`'
    }
```

After I run the command `gradle grails-dbm-gorm-diff -PgrailsArgs="2015-5-23-first-diff.groovy --add"`, I got error like below.

```
| Starting dbm-gorm-diff
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: 列 "PASSWD" が見つかりません
Column "PASSWD" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT passwd FROM USER WHERE 1 = 0 [42122-176]
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.createSnapshot(JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.java:251)
    at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(DatabaseSnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:69)
    at liquibase.diff.Diff.compare(Diff.java:71)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.GormDiff.compare(GormDiff.groovy:45)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.ScriptUtils.createAndPrintFixedDiff(ScriptUtils.groovy:244)
    at DbmGormDiff$_run_closure1_closure2_closure3.doCall(DbmGormDiff:53)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils.executeInSession(MigrationUtils.groovy:133)
    at DbmGormDiff$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall(DbmGormDiff:50)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.ScriptUtils.executeAndWrite(ScriptUtils.groovy:104)
    at DbmGormDiff$_run_closure1.doCall(DbmGormDiff:49)
    at org.grails.launcher.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:57)
    at org.grails.launcher.context.DelegatingGrailsLaunchContext.launch(DelegatingGrailsLaunchContext.java:409)
    at org.grails.launcher.ReflectiveGrailsLauncher.launch(ReflectiveGrailsLauncher.java:32)
    at org.grails.launcher.InProcessGrailsLauncher.launch(InProcessGrailsLauncher.java:27)
    at org.grails.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:62)
    at org.grails.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:38)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: 列 "PASSWD" が見つかりません
Column "PASSWD" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT passwd FROM USER WHERE 1 = 0 [42122-176]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:178)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:154)
    at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.optimize(ExpressionColumn.java:148)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.prepare(Select.java:831)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:248)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:442)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:384)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1188)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcStatement.java:75)
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.isColumnAutoIncrement(JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.java:842)
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.readColumns(JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.java:369)
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.createSnapshot(JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.java:244)
    ... 15 more
:grails-dbm-gorm-diff FAILED
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the JIRA the solution is as follows:

> This is caused by the backticks that escape the 'password' field in
>   the generated user class. 'password' is a reserved word in some
>   databases so the script escapes it by default since if it's not a
>   reserved word it has no effect. So either remove "password column:
>   '`password`'" if it isn't a reserved word, or change it to a
>   non-reserved word without a backtick if it is, e.g. "password column:
>   'passwd'"

This means you need to edit your `User` domain class.

**Update** Your domain class should look like this:

```
String username
String password
static transients = ['springSecurityService']
static constraints = {
    username blank: false, unique: true
    password blank: false
}
static mapping = {
    // NOTICE THE FOLLOWING FIELD DOES NOT HAVE BACKTICKS!
    password column: 'passwd'
}
```

Comment: How can I edit my `User` domain class that is created by **Spring Security Plugin** ?

Comment: It makes the error, `ERROR twitter.TwitterAuthFilter  - Failed processing twitter callback. Message: No such property: password for class: User. Possible solutions: passwd`, after simply changed the property name of User Class. I'm using Spring Security Twitter, too.

Comment: Find the User.groovy class that was created when you ran the s2-quickstart script, and make the edits indicated in the answer. Which should be as easy as removing the entire "password column ..." part within the mapping (Since you are using H2).

Comment: Unfortunately, I got the error by db-diff command even thought I changed "password column" to "passwd". I'll update my question.

Comment: You don't need the back-tick characters around the field name. That's what's causing the issue in both cases. Remove them and you won't have any problems.

Comment: I want to use the spring security login with username and password, so I do not want to remove password from User.groovy.

Comment: I edited the answer to show you what I am talking about. You don't need to remove password, just the backticks from the name. As the JIRA points out .

Comment: I changed my User.groovy static mapping to `static mapping = {
    // NOTICE THE FOLLOWING FIELD DOES NOT HAVE BACKTICKS!
    password column: 'passwd'
}`
But I got the error shown in the UPDATE part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem as well, but was able to fix it by changing:

```
grails dbm-gorm-diff ...
```

to

```
grails test dbm-gorm-diff ...
```

My development environment (default) is set to use an H2 database, but my test environment (the one this command was intended for) was set to use postgres.