# grails database migration "Column not found" error

Tags: grails, database-migration

I'm using the grails database migration plugin: `runtime ':database-migration:1.4.1'`. For the initial changelog everything seems to work, even going from an H2 development database to mysql.

However, I wanted to test an actual model change, and I'm getting an error I can't figure out.

We have the following User model:

```
class User {

    // spring security params:
    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password

    // Added this to test model changes: 
    String removeme

    ...

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }
}
```

When I go to generate the diff, i.e.

`grails dbm-gorm-diff --add change_test.groovy`

I get the following exception:

```
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "PASSWORD" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT password FROM user WHERE 1 = 0 [42122-176]
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.createSnapshot(JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.java:251)
    at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(DatabaseSnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:69)
    at liquibase.diff.Diff.compare(Diff.java:71)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.GormDiff.compare(GormDiff.groovy:45)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.ScriptUtils.createAndPrintFixedDiff(ScriptUtils.groovy:244)
    at DbmGormDiff$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure3.doCall(DbmGormDiff:53)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils.executeInSession(MigrationUtils.groovy:137)
    at DbmGormDiff$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(DbmGormDiff:50)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.ScriptUtils.executeAndWrite(ScriptUtils.groovy:104)
    at DbmGormDiff$_run_closure1.doCall(DbmGormDiff:49)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "PASSWORD" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT password FROM user WHERE 1 = 0 [42122-176]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:178)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:154)
    at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.optimize(ExpressionColumn.java:148)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.prepare(Select.java:831)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:248)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:442)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:384)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1188)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcStatement.java:75)
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.isColumnAutoIncrement(JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.java:842)
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.readColumns(JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.java:369)
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.createSnapshot(JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.java:244)
```

I can simply remove the `removeme` column and everything works as expected. This is only in our dev environment too, so only regarding the H2 database.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this pretty much based on this answer:

[How can I use Grails DB Migration with Spring Security and the default DB, H2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411603/how-can-i-use-grails-db-migration-with-spring-security-and-the-default-db-h2)

Changed this

```
static mapping = {
    password column: '`password`'
}
```

to

```
static mapping = {
    password column: 'passwd'
}
```

Basically the above is preferred (IMO) because it avoids confusion in the database engine, and having to deal with weird escaping -- by just using something that isn't generally a reserved word.